# d3 elements not showing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using react with d3js, but for some reason the d3 container div is not rendering. I suspect that something is not done correctly when selecting the local div, but I can't figure out what.

The index.html & the index.js files are just plain boilerplate code and the only modification is in the App.jsx file posted below

```
import React from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

function App() {
  const data = [
    { name: "A", score: 70 },
    { name: "B", score: 90 },
    { name: "C", score: 50 }
  ];

  const width = 800;
  const height = 800;
  const margin = { top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 50 };

  const svg = d3
    .select("#container")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right)
    .attr("height", height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
    .attr("viewbox", [0, 0, width, height]);

  const x = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.range(data.length))
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .padding(0.1);

  const y = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("fill", "royalblue")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data.sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.score, b.score)))
    .join("rect")
    .attr("x", (d, i) => x(i))
    .attr("y", (d) => y(d.score))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", (d) => y(0) - y(d.score));

  svg.node();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Chart</h1>
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the state of the world as your code runs:

- The `App` component is rendered on page load.
- We call `d3.select('#container')`, but nothing happens. There's no div with that ID on the page because we haven't gotten that far yet.
- The D3 operations continue, likely throwing no errors because by design, D3 allows you to operate on empty selections.
- We return a JSX value describing the DOM we want React to render. Sometime shortly after we return this, the elements are rendered into the page.
- Now we have the `#container` element but our selection code does not re-run, because nothing triggers the component to re-render.

You might consider using a callback ref - here's a minimal example:

```js
const doD3Stuff = (element) => {
  const width = 800;
  const height = 800;
  const margin = { top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 50 };

  const svg = d3
    // the select method can accept an actual element instead of a selector
    .select(element)
    .append("svg");

  // etc.
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Chart</h1>
      <div id="container" ref={doD3Stuff} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is a starting point, but of course it doesn't get into what happens when data changes and you want to things to redraw, animate, etc.

React and D3 [can work well together](https://wattenberger.com/blog/react-and-d3). But even when using just one of them by itself, it's good to understand the execution model - when code runs, and when it doesn't. When using them together, it's way more important to have this level of understanding, or things will happen that you'll have difficulty troubleshooting.